# Invert fn key use of PGUP/HOME and PGDN/END keys

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to invert the <kbd>Fn</kbd>-key behaviour of the <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> keys on my MSI laptop. Currently I need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to get <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to get <kbd>End</kbd>, and since I use <kbd>Home</kbd> (<kbd>End</kbd>) a lot more than <kbd>PgUp</kbd> (<kbd>PgDn</kbd>), I would like to invert this setting so that I can use <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. How can I achieve this for only these two keys?

Running Linux Mint 17.3 on a MSI GE62 2QD Apache.